# How should I be passing data to my view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm currently doing things all over the place, but I'm using a specific method in a ContentFactory class to generate the view for a request:

```
ob_start();
include ($file);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $content;
```

Within a calling class, a view class, this is how I get the content:

```
public function userSummaryAjax(User $userObj){

    global $user;

    $user = $userObj;

    $content = ContentFactory::capture_output(templates . 'adminUserSummaryAjax.php');

    return $content;
}
```

This is what a basic controller looks like:

```
public function userlistView()
{

    $dataArray = $this->helper->getListUsers();

    $content = $this->view->userlistView($dataArray);

    $page = new page();
    $page->setPageTitle("Users");
    $page->setH1("Users");
    $page->setlead("A list of active users");
    $page->setContent($content);
}
```

How can I improve what I have to make it much better, simpler?

Unfortunately, if I could decouple Zend/Mvc/View and use something from that, that'd be ok

Comment: Why do you say unfortunately? Did you mean you can't Also, I'd look at Symfony. Between Sonata, FOSUserBundle, Silex, et al, you have a lot tools. I don't event want to ask why you have `global $user;` in there.

Comment: You shouldn't. In proper MVC implementation the view instances request data from model layer. Also, on the other note: **stop using global state!**. Either in form of global or static variables.

Comment: I'm slowly getting rid of the globals - I did a quick dump on $GLOBALS, and it's baffling to see how much there is there. If the View is requesting data from the model layer, well, I can't really picture it in my head?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Is it even possible to use ZF2 Mvc without it's structure?

Comment: Some people (including myself) prefer to use the controller as a sort of medium between the view and models. So you would load up a view inside the controller and then assign data to it that you fetched from the models.

Comment: @Supericy Just updated the post with what's in my controller for this.

Comment: Supposedly. Symfony is very specifically constructed to be componentized, decoupled and interchangeable. Drupal is adopting some of their core components in Drupal 8, for instance.  But what is in that question is *ZF2 MVC*?

Comment: ZFS? I was referring to seeing if I could implement some components of Zend/Mvc (ZF2) into the application I have, given that I'm already using ZF2 components.

Comment: Packagist: [Symphony2 Bundles](https://packagist.org/search/?q=symfony2). Also for development, check out [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/).

Comment: @JaredFarrish Haven't had much experience with Symphony - but I've heard good things about their DI/IoC

Comment: Hmm, use some nice framework. Symfony is one of them, but Nette is awesome. http://doc.nette.org/en/presenters

Comment: @Shamil *".. well, I can't really picture it in my head"*. You have to begin with understanding that **view is not a template**. It is an instance which handles all of the UI logic. In web context it usually means "create a response for the user". It juggles multiple template to assemble HTML output, when necessary. While in some cases it just returns a HTTP location header (that also is a response).

Comment: The page object, which I'm using creates the page and returns the output - would this not classify as handling the UI logic?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use clases and objects for improve the implementation.

The controller in php should be responsable for get the data and put in the view.

In this case the function userListView should receive in params all the models necessary.

Comment: Ideally, I'd have something in the controller such as `$this->view->_load('list')->data($array);` ?

Comment: -1: no, controller should be only responsible for changing the state of model layer and current view, using the data from user input.

Comment: That is when the change of state is first, but if i have only get the info?